# Set the base URL in the page when using Spring MVC 3

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am learning the Spring MVC 3 now.

I meet some problems when set the URLs in my page, since the URL in the page are relatived to the current page, so I want to set the base URL in each page.

When I use Structs 2, I create a BaseAction like this:

```
public class BaseAction{
  public BaseAction(){
     string baseURL=getServletContext.getHost()+"...."+.....;
  }
  public getBaseURL(){xxxxx}
}
```

Then in the page:

```
<base href='<s:prototype value="baseURL"/>' />
```

Now, in Spring MVC 3, since the a new instance of related controller is not created for each request, so I do not know how to make it?

Finally, I think I can use the interceptor, so I create a interceptor:

```
public class BaseURLInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {
        return true;
    }

    //after the handler is executed
    public void postHandle(
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
        Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView)
        throws Exception {
        modelAndView.getModel().setObject("baseURL",requset.getHost()+"......");
    }
```

}

In the page:

I can use :

```
<base href="${baseURL}" />
```

It works, however when a view is redirected, it will add this value to the URL.

For example:

```
@Controller
@RequsetMapping("/user")
public class UserController{

    @RequsetMapping("edit/{userid}")
    public String edit(@PathVariable String uid)
        //edit logic
        return "redirect:list"
    }

    @RequsetMapping("list")
    public String list(){
        //get users list
        return "user_list"
    }
}
```

When I make the submit button in the user edit page, I will redirect to :

```
http://localhost:8080/app/user/list?baseURL=http://localhost:8080
```

Where the parameter in the url  `?baseURL=http://localhost:8080` is not what I want.

How to fix it?

Or what is the better way to solve the URL path using Spring MVC 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I do not correct understand the problem, but if you want to have the base url in the `jsp` for some links than your approach is the wrong one.

normaly you would do something like this:

test

And for redirects in the controller you can specify how the url has to be interpreted if you use [`RedirectView`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/) instead of returning the String "redirect:xxx": the redirect view constructor [`RedirectView(String url, boolean contextRelative)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html#RedirectView%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) can be used to specify context relative to the current ServletContext or relative to the web server.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly this is what you're looking for `<base href="<c:url value="${webappRoot}" />`

Comment: the value of ${webapprRoot} is empty